# How to get firebase functions (typescript) files to auto transpile with a react app/firebase emulators on save?

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have working React app (create-react-app) that uses firebase, and firebase functions. Previously, functions used regular js, but I recently migrated to Typescript for those functions. The react app also uses typescript.

Previously, any changes to functions were automatically picked up by the emulator and I could see it register those functions in the terminal window running the following cmmand:

`firebase emulators:start --import ./firestore --export-on-exit --inspect-functions`

With the functions migration to typescript I have the following problems:

1. The new function typescript files are not being compiled on save any longer.
2. I have to open the functions folder in a new window and run `npm run build` to get it to transpile (?) the typescript into js files, then it will work.
3. Running npm run build in the functions folder throws a node_module error.

I want to open my primary project, edit a functions ts file, save it, and get it to transpile... I believe that will get it to work in the emulator in the hot reload fashion (pardon me if I am missusing terms).

This is the folder structure generated by firebase tools that I am using.

```
|-functions
|---src
|------index.ts
|---lib
|------functions/src/index.js
|---tsconfig.json
|---package.json

|-src
|-tsconfig.json
|-package.json
```

My assumption is that the root folder tsconfig and package.json are controlling what happens and say nothing about `tsc` - The functions folder files of the same name mention tsc, but aren't doing any kind of hot reloading and I have to type "npm run build" after every change to see if it works.

functions/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]

  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

functions package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendinblue/client": "^3.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Root folder tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "webpack.config.ts", "public/firebase-messaging-sw.js", "declarations.d.ts" ]
}
```

Root folder package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "ts-coverage": "typescript-coverage-report"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.6",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "typescript-coverage-report": "^0.6.4"
  }
}
```

I've attempted to use tsconfig `extends` and `includes` to get it to work the way it was, but without success. Any guidance on the items listed would be greatly appreciated.